# How to avoid calling a function that gets a score twice in an ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an `ng-repeat` div that loops over an array, and then inside that ng-repeat, I call a function that takes the element and returns a score based on it like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="game in games track by $index">
    <span>{{ getScore(game) }}<i class="icon ion-checkmark-bold" ng-if="!getScore(game)"></i></span>
</div>
```

The problem is that I call `getScore()` twice every `ng-repeat` and I was wondering if there's a way for me to change my code so I only call it once, and then pass the result to both places.

I did try using `ng-init` like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="game in games track by $index" ng-init="score = getScore(game)">
    <span>{{ score }}<i class="icon ion-checkmark-bold" ng-if="!score)"></i></span>
</div>
```

However, I noticed that this doesn't work, and the score result ends up being the same for all the repeats.

Comment: do the scores change in real time? Or are they static? If static, wht not just preprocess your array to contain the scores? With a live collection, ng-repeat will cause your inline `getScore` to run everytime the `games` array is affected which can be troublesome as well

Comment: Also, have you tried `{{ :getScore(game) }}` (with the colon)?